# What are good ways to find collaborators for a coding weekend?

Tags: game-design, open-source

Not sure if this belongs here, feel free to push it somewhere else if needed.

When i was at university we would sometimes come together into a room full of beer and fast food and crank out software in a weekend. Unfortunately the group has kind of split up and its just not possible any more.

My question is now: Where can i find like-minded people on the Internet that would like to do something like this? I have an idea what i wanted to do next, but of course other people have ideas too.

Comment: +1 even though this question is off-topic, because I'm also interested in something like this. If you live in a small town, it can be really hard to find the like-minden people online.

Comment: I think people are rather using Internet for this, nowadays. You can send screenshots and other things pretty easily, and talk using Skype.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Yeah, but that takes away most of the fun ("a room full of beer and fast food").

Comment: you can check out Game dev chat room. maybe you find some people interested in your project there.

Comment: shame this has to be closed for being OT. anyways, marton if you want contact me sameguy@gmx.de. Maybe something can be worked out. I have never been to game dev chat. Are these guys nice to new people?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest searching in [Meetup](http://www.meetup.com/) for a relevant group.  I'm a member of two groups that are local to me and focused on mobile development.  One often sponsors "hackathons" like you describe for prizes.